# Can receive but not send SMS

Tags: sms

My Samsung Galaxy 2 (SC-02C) has been rooted and upgraded to 4.1.2. It seemed that everything, all phone functionality, was fine.

However, I've discovered that I can not *send* SMS with my phone. I can *receive* SMS from anyone from any carrier in my area just fine. I've asked at my service provider (DoCoMo, in Japan) and was told that I have the service enabled and my account with them should be fully operational.

I wouldn't have imagined rooting and upgrading the phone would impact SMS, but that seems to be the case.

How might my SMS functionality be impacted by my current ROM, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason I assumed that SMS functionality was integral to the phone, not the OS, and so it would be reliant on carrier configurations and settings. As a result, I automatically went looking for some kind of solution that involved ROMs or kernels and whatnot.

However, it turns out that there are SMS apps available on Google Play, and I was able to solve this by simply using an app other than the default. In my case, I chose [Handcent](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.nextsms&hl=en). SMS works perfectly fine.

So it was only the default SMS app that was the problem, not anything more fundamental.

Comment: Any idea *why*?

Comment: @tremby, No, sorry, I never figured out what was wrong with the default SMS app. And since posting this question, I have changed devices, so the conditions that went into this are now lost to history.

Comment: Too bad. I have a similar issue (posted at http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159431/sms-sending-to-some-contacts-but-not-others-in-messaging-app)

Answer (score 3):

It could be a ROM bug - have you communicated to the author/thread of the ROM and asked if there are any issues with SMS sending?

If there aren't, I suggest that you wipe factory data completely, and then try again. You may wish to use an app such as [My Backup Root](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rerware.android.MyBackupRoot) or [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) to back up your apps before you do so.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have asked about the ROM with the developer. I'm hoping there might be a solution that does not involve wiping the phone (again), unless I know for sure it will fix it. I've been playing a lot of feature-whack-a-mole recently, and I'd like to stop.

Comment: @DaveMG I know the feeling, and I cannot say for sure that wiping will work. One more thing - your network aren't having any service issues are they?

Comment: It's hard to imagine network issues are the cause since I can receive fine, and all other functions like phone and mail work. However, in any case, my service provider assured me the network was fine.

Comment: @DaveMG There was once a network issue in my area that stopped sending SMS - everything else worked, but OK. You will have to wait for the dev to reply :)

Comment: Fair enough. :)